# Brackets, configure proxy

Tags: json, proxy, editor, adobe-brackets

I want to use [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) (at best) but it's impossible to install extensions.

Indeed I have a proxy, I configured the brackets.json file like (check this https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets)

```
"proxy" : "http://username:password​@server:port/"
```

I use the same synthax like .npmrc file for node.js and that work, but with brackets, impossible to access extensions.

I try to install extensions with zip file but with this method, extensions don't work properly.

Any idea ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.The thing I was missing was a comma after the above element, here **"downloadCount"**

As my college proxy server is 172.16.30.80 and port is 8080,my brackets.json file looked like this

```
{
"brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
"brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
"fonts.fontSize": "12px",
"fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
"themes.theme": "delkos",
"extensions.sort": "downloadCount",
"proxy": "http://172.16.30.80:8080"

}
```

I have just added

```
"proxy": "http://172.16.30.80:8080"
```

For those who don't know, you can edit brackets.json file by selecting Open Preference File option of Debug in menu bar.